# Cannot deploy to Heroku - Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'

Tags: django, python-3.x, git, heroku

I have in the past successfully deployed a Django-Webapp to Heroku, but this time I cannot do it. I've tried following the suggestion "remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1" on my terminal. On my settings.py I've tried to follow third party tutorials as well as Heroku's documentation. At this point I'm totally clueless on what should I do.

```
Successfully installed Django-3.0.1 asgiref-3.2.3 attrs-19.3.0 beautifulsoup4-4.8.2 bootstrap4-0.1.0 certifi-2019.11.28 chardet-3.0.4 dj-database-url-0.5.0 django-bootstrap4-1.1.1 django-crispy-forms-1.8.1 django-forms-bootstrap-3.1.0 django-heroku-0.3.1 gunicorn-20.0.4 idna-2.6 importlib-metadata-1.3.0 jsonschema-3.2.0 more-itertools-8.0.2 psycopg2-2.7.3.2 pyrsistent-0.15.6 python-decouple-3.1 pytz-2019.3 requests-2.18.4 requests-unixsocket-0.1.5 six-1.13.0 soupsieve-1.9.5 sqlparse-0.3.0 urllib3-1.22 whitenoise-5.0.1 zipp-0.6.0
remote: 
remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
remote:            main()
remote:          File "manage.py", line 17, in main
remote:            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
remote:            utility.execute()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
remote:            settings.INSTALLED_APPS
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
remote:            self._setup(name)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
remote:            self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
remote:            mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
remote:            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
remote:          File "/tmp/build_fcba15a1a9550bb36762a97c2d148678/gtc/settings.py", line 91, in <module>
remote:            default=config('DATABASE_URL')
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/decouple.py", line 197, in __call__
remote:            return self.config(*args, **kwargs)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/decouple.py", line 85, in __call__
remote:            return self.get(*args, **kwargs)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/decouple.py", line 70, in get
remote:            raise UndefinedValueError('{} not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value.'.format(option))
remote:        decouple.UndefinedValueError: DATABASE_URL not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value.
remote: 
remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
remote:        See traceback above for details.
remote: 
remote:        You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
remote:        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
remote: 
remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
remote: 
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to weatherappsky.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/weatherappsky.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/weatherappsky.git'
```

Any advice? Thank you

Comment: DATABASE_URL not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value.

Comment: That doesn't help me much